# Formato de data/hora de now() em mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$verificatempo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs
WHERE horario <= now() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
AND ip = '$ipaddress'
ORDER BY horario desc limit 1");
```

Gostaria de saber o formato de data e hora idêntico ao **now()** que foi usado na linha de código do mysql para comparação. Se possível, pode ser um código em si igual.

Comment: horario é yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss? ou só a hora (hh:ii:ss)?

Comment: Formato "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS" se usado em um contexto de string
Formato YYYYMMDDHHMMSS se usado em um contexto numérico nas versões do MySQL antes do MySQL 4.1.13
Formato YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu se usado em um contexto numérico nas versões do MySQL 4.1.13 e mais recente

Answer (score 0):

A função `NOW()` retorna a data e a hora atuais no fuso horário configurado como uma string ou um número no formato `YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: DD` ou `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu`.

O tipo retornado depende do contexto em que é usado.

### Exemplos

`SELECT NOW();`

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]